# Active Storage to work within and engine with action text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage, actiontext

I have my main rails application and I am using an Engine already as Mount.
I am using the same model in my engine too

`class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  has_rich_text :body
end`

I am able to use action text with active storage outside the engine but within my engine only action text part is working and I am not getting any routes/action on uploading an image from action text for active record.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?